# unable to identify the error while trying to access an array index

Tags: php

The following php code :

```
<?php
class foo {
   $arr = array("First","Second","Third","Fourth");
}

$obj = new foo();
echo $obj->$arr[1];
?>
```

---

generates the following error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$arr' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tester.php on line 3
```

I am using php5.4 . What is this error ? How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

When accessing a property of an object, you don't use a `$`. Just `echo $obj->arr[1]` will do fine.

EDIT: Also, as Explosion Pills says, you need to specify a visibility. In this case, you probably want

```
public $arr = array("First","Second","Third","Fourth");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php says it is a valid syntax but I get an error if I put the dollar sign. why is that

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `private|public|protected` in front of `$arr`

Additionally, access with `$obj->arr[1]` instead, but `$obj->$arr[1]` is in fact valid syntax.

It is valid syntax because it will be interpolated as a string with the variable name.  This will work, for example:

```
$arr = array(1 => 'arr');
$obj->$arr[1];
```

That interpolates to `$obj->arr`

Comment: I get an error `Undefined variable: arr` if I use the dollar sign . ($obj->$arr[1])even after putting the public access